# SQL Server timeout on specific record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
UPDATE Table SET Field = @value WHERE id = @id
```

`id` is the primary key.

When I execute this query against an arbitrary record, it works fine and returns almost imediately. But when I execute it against id `178413` specifically it runs forever, until a timeout is triggered.

No queries should be locking this record for more than a few milliseconds.

The server runs SQL Server 2012.

What can be happening?

Comment: 1.  That specific record (or the page that record is one) is locked, thus blocking.   2.  See if there is a trigger on the table......and that specific item......causes the trigger to do some crazy voodoo.

Comment: When this is "running forever" check sys.dm_exec_requests to see if there is a blocking_session_id, then find out what that session is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Apparently one of the clients has crashed and kept the database connection open, probably in the middle of a transaction.

As soon as I restarted the faulty program, the record become updatable again.